# How to create an instance by an existing object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumber, objective-c-runtime

I've tried the following codes. it crashed

```
    NSNumber* a = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithLong:12];
    NSNumber* b = [[NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithUTF8String:object_getClassName(a)]) alloc] initWithLong:12];
```

the following codes also crashed.

```
    NSNumber* a = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithLong:12];
    NSNumber* b = [[a class] alloc] initWithLong:12];
```

but the following codes worked

```
    NSNumber* b = [[NSClassFromString(@"NSString") alloc] initWithLong:12]
```

when I want to get the class name from a NSNumber's instance. It's always return "__NSCFNumber" rather than "NSNumber". why?

Comment: +1 for such a nice question, I never thought this in cocoa, will try to solve this, if cocoa allows :p

Answer (score 4):

NSNumber is an "abstract class", meaning that while it represents multiple classes, objects that it generates will not respond to the `class` message in a way you might expect.

You can learn more about abstract classes in [Apple's documentation on class clusters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html).